# How do I provide wired connections with internet while leeching off of a wireless network?

Tags: 11.04, wireless, networking

I want to connect a desktop pc to my laptop and use the wireless ability of my laptop to give my desktop internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's very easy. I do that all the time. Click the network icon in your panel and open network properties. Select your wired interface and click edit to configure it. In IPv4 Settings, choose Method: Shared with other computers.

That's it. You don't have to do anything on the client (in your case, desktop). Your wireless network is now shared on your wired network. You just have to plug it in :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is here:

- Ubuntu GUI and CLI:
  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Internet/ConnectionSharing
- Classic linux howto: http://www.howtoforge.com/nat_iptables

Just remember:

- WAN - in this case your wireless network
- LAN - in this case your laptop-desktop connection

Edit: Bonus - exactly the same problem at ubuntuforums.org - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=363156

Comment: Will my having one network card in my laptop hinder my ability to do this?

Comment: You probably have two network cards. Ethernet (wired) and WiFi (wireless) are two network cards.

Comment: That's a horribly complicated way of doing it. There is a much easier way. -1

Comment: You're assuming both of those computers are already connected and you're assuming he's using gnome. Plus your solution is exactly the same as first point in the first link I provided, which means you haven't actually read it. Just because I gave him several options in case he couldn't use the first one doesn't mean it's complicated.

Comment: Hey it might be a little in depth, but it was still follow-able. Thanks anonymous87